# MapBox Vector Tiles Overlay using MKTileOverlay in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapbox, mkmapview

We are attempting to overlay MapBox vector tiles on a MapKit map, so far to no avail. The MKTileOverlay obviously doesn't support MVTs, so what MapKit function would allow us to overlay these tiles (including features, zoom levels, etc.) to our existing Apple Map?

Using raster tiles is not an option for our use case. The tiles must be vector tiles.

```
func addMap() {
    let url = "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/1/0/0.mvt?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    
    let tileOverlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: url)
    
    mapView.addOverlay(tileOverlay)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple MapKit [docs for `MKTileOverlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay), raster or *bitmap images* are required.

> *An overlay that covers an area of the map with tiles of **bitmap images**.*

---

Since MapKit for iOS expects rasters, it is *possible* to make use of the Mapbox [Raster Tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/raster-tiles/) API to serve up raster versions of your Mapbox tiles.

Your Swift URL would look like this:

```swift
let url = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

---

You can see an example of what the Mapbox Raster Tile API serves (this is noted in the Mapbox Docs).

```sh
curl https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/256/9/89/206@2x?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

---

[image]